# Git clone gives 403 error on localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, git

I have been following the steps on this page:

[Hosting a Git server under Apache on Windows](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/) but at step 5 I run

```
git clone http://localhost/Test.git
```

and I get the response

```
Cloning into Test...
fatal: unable to access 'http://localhost/Test.git/': The requested URL returned error 403
```

I already used the answer to this question [Setting up Git / Apache on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/361539/setting-up-git-apache-on-windows) to solve a problem with the previous step. I have also tried adding

```
<Directory "c:/program files/git/libexec/git-core">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

As was suggested in the comments at the bottom of the original page.

Can anyone explain/solve the 403 error?

**Edit**

There is no `git-daemon-export-ok` file in the repo I'm trying to clone - should there be one? (In my searching I keep coming across this but am unsure whether it is needed)

Comment: You seem to be missing a `//`. Try `git clone http://localhost/Test.git`

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, that was a typo in my question - I've corrected it now. That is the exact command I run

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing

```
<Directory />
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

which is an important change form Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4.

Whether this completely solves everything or simply hides it until a later time I don't know though.